# EF Power Tools confused by Self Referential Table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, poco

I'm using the Visual Studio Entity Framework power tools to generate poco classes from my DB.  It worked until I added a self referencing key to a table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
  [parentItemId] [int] NULL,
...
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_Item] FOREIGN KEY([parentItemId])
```

Now my item class is the same as it was before (it doesn't contain the new *parentItemId* field):

```
public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And it seems the power tools have failed to generate any code at all inside the dbContext class.

Is it beyond EF to work with this kind of DB structure?

If so then what's the best solution?  The only one I can think of is to add another table **ItemItem** and create a many to many relationship (which is overkill but...)

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634996/entity-framework-how-do-i-map-a-self-referencial-foreign-key-eg-category-has?rq=1 ?

Comment: I hadn't seen that.  I will check that now and update soon.  Thanks

Comment: I can't find the EntityConfiguration type so I used EntityTypeConfiguration instead and a new mapping of: this.Property(t => t.Parent.Id).HasColumnName("parentItemId");  But I get an error: "he type 'DataAccess.Models.Item' has already been configured as an entity type. It cannot be reconfigured as a complex type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find some of the classes in that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634996/entity-framework-how-do-i-map-a-self-referencial-foreign-key-eg-category-has?rq=1).  I did get this working using another [article](http://www.codecapers.com/post/Using-Self-Referencing-Tables-With-Entity-Framework.aspx).  The Item class ended up as:

```
public partial class Item
 ...
    public virtual int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping class needed:

```
this.HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
    .WithMany(x => x.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

It seemed to work.  I didn't need any of the ProxyCreation or CreateObject commands...  The big problem is that I can't use the EF power tools anymore to generate any new Poco classes.